# Syntax Error when trying to import csv using sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, jupyter-lab

I am trying to import a csv file into my jupyter notebook using sqlite3 but I keep getting a syntax error. I have already downloaded the csv.

```
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import yellow_tripdata_2016-01.csv taxi
```

I keep getting the error.

```
    $ sqlite3
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

or when I delete $ sqlite3 and tried to import sqlite3 first and only run

```
sqlite> .import yellow_tripdata_2016-01.csv taxi
```

I also got a syntax error

```
    sqlite> .mode csv
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help. Thank you

Comment: `SyntaxError` is a [Python error](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/errors.html#syntax-errors). That suggests you are typing `sqlite` commands at a Python prompt. Instead, run `sqlite3` from a terminal, not from within a jupyter notebook.

Comment: If you want to access `sqlite` from within a Python script, then use the [sqlite3 python module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: The `$` is a generic shell prompt, and `sqlite>` the sqlite3 command prompt. You don't actually type them; especially not into a *python* session.